# Raspi not 'accepting' JUH340 USB Hub. (Raspbian OS)

Tags: raspbian, usb, power, hub, usb3

Easily, not too many people have asked a question about this model of usb hub.
What I'm attempting to use is a J5 CREATE JUH340 USB 3.0 with the RPi, but it is highly unworkable. With most everything plugged in as should be (USB 3.0 host cord plugged into RPI, included power cable plugged into the same power strip as the Rpi, etc.), too many problems come up.

First, the hub doesn't seem to supply the attached keyboard and mouse with any power (both of which are certainly supported by the RPi).

Second, the Pi won't 'accept' the hub, in turn not recieving any input from the peripherals plugged into the hub, and also, displays repeated lines of 'device descriptor read/64, error -71', 'device not accepting address (5, 67, 8, 9', and the like. However, in earlier messages, I see that the pi recognizes the device, with it printing out 'device manufacturer: VIA technologies' and 'detected 4 USB ports'.

Would anyone happen to know a solution to this problem?

Comment: The solution may be to use a hub known to work.  Have you seen http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs

Comment: That is a possible fix, but I would like to see If this hub would work at all, because it is definitely a nice one.